# ImportError: No module named dns.exception

Tags: python, dns, mx-record, dnspython

I am trying to use the [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) in my code but when it gets to the import statement, I get the following error:

```
>>> import DNS.resolver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\DNS\resolver.py", line 31, in <module>
    import dns.exception
ImportError: No module named dns.exception
```

I have tried installing with pip, easy_install and manually from the git repo but nothing seems to do the trick. Any ideas??

Code:

```
import DNS.resolver

if __name__ == "__main__":

    domain = 'hotmail.com'
    for x in dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX'):
        print x.to_text()
```

Comment: what happens when you try `import DNS`?

Comment: `Import DNS` works but then I get, `NameError Occured name "dns" is not defined` at this line `dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')`

Comment: Ah hah! `import DNS` is for another module called [pydns](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do to fix problems with this package is to install **python-dnspython** again using Synaptic. (Whether no having previous problems about duplicity)

Sometimes if you try to install this package using **pip** could appear some problems like that:

> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip_build_root/dnspython Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log

Using Synaptic cleans the old files and install the new ones, from that package. I know this issue is solved but I wanted to add more information about this :)

Comment: Until I saw your answer I was trying `pip install dns`. Thanks for the heads up that the package is actually called **dnspython**.

Comment: Yes, but run `pip install dnspython`

Answer (score 2):

That's because package and module names are lowercase (see [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)). This works just fine :

```
import dns.resolver
import dns.exception
```

You should also be careful that none of your own *.py filename conflicts with the dns package. Your *.py file should not be named dns.py. Pay also attention to the *.pyc files.

Comment: How did you name your *.py file ?

Comment: Hmm the name is completely different and the error happens in the interpreter as well

Comment: That is weird. Your piece of code works just fine. Check in all directories in your python path that no custom module is conflicting.

Comment: You're correct! It was conflicting with another module I had installed, [PyDNS](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thanks for your answer ...actually my issue was my file name. so, guys don't name your file with any conflict names like dns.py or like that

Answer (score 2):

First, your code should be : `import dns.resolver`.

There seems to be an issue installing **dnspython** using pip, you should clone the **dnspython** repository using git and run the file **setup.py** as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython
cd dnspython\
python setup.py install
```

If you don't have git installed on your machine, you can just download the repository manually .